# Is there a strategy to win chess960 games?

Tags: opening, strategy, chess-variants, chess960

Chess960, a variant where the backrank pieces are all randomized [subject to a few constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer_random_chess), is a variant of chess where you cannot really memorize openings. Is there a strategy in chess960 so it is easy to win the game?

Maybe controlling the center or developing the opposite side of where the king is?

Comment: Related: [What are the best scoring openings in Chess960?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2569/26335), [What are the basic principles to play chess960?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4097/26335)

Answer (score 1):

Stick with basic chess principles. Through trial and error, you'll find your style.